# ruby/rake/rspec cannot load spec_helper (not rails)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to set up a testing environment for a ruby project using Rake and Rspec.

When I try to run "rake" in the console I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from spec/numbersTest_spec.rb:1:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

My filetree looks like this:

```
project
-spec
--numbersTest_spec.rb
--spec_helper.rb
-rakefile
```

rakefile

```
begin
    require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

    task default: %w[test]

    task :test do
        ruby "spec/numbersTest_spec.rb"
    end
end
```

numbersTest_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Imperative" do
 perfectImperative(5).should == false 
end
```

Comment: Does it work if you just run `rspec` in your `project` directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'
```

instead of `require ...` in `numbersTest_spec.rb` will solve this problem.

The reason is that `numbersTest_spec.rb` has no clue where to look the required file for. `require` expects an argument to be available on global require path. To solve this in general, one might update `$:` (global require path), by e.g.:

```
$:.unshift "#{`pwd`}".chomp
```

But in your particular case relative requiring is the silver bullet. In fact, [bundler](http://bundler.io/) was invented to forget about loading path managing horror.